# Mysql dialect cannot be fount in knex (browserified)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I've recently started to work on NodeJS, and in particular the knex module to query and insert into databases from the browser.

I've tested my code on my own computer, which worked. For the browser, however, I needed to use the module browserify to transform my code in the right manner (into a bundle.js file).

But, when I load the file in the browser, it gives me an error stating the following:

bundle.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './dialects/mysql/index.js'

In the coding, the error gets thrown after this part:

```
var Dialect;
if (arguments.length === 0 || !config.client && !config.dialect) {
Dialect = makeClient(Client);
} else {
var clientName = config.client || config.dialect;
Dialect = makeClient(require("./dialects/" + (aliases[clientName] ||clientName) + "/index"));
}
```

After this, and error is thrown, while the file does actually exist in the path that is specified. furthermore, lines of code before this, like for example:

```
var Readable = require('./_stream_readable');
var Writable = require('./_stream_writable');
```

Do actually work fine, so I guess it cannot be that the function is searching in the wrong directory. I'm running out of new ideas on how to possibly fix this, so I'm hoping that someone knows a bit more about this.

Comment: I don't think browserify supports dynamic requires so you can't use require inside if statement, there are some workarounds tho. Another thing is that if the error is caused by knex module then you should know that knex is only server side. It can't be used on client.

Comment: I guess I can try getting this part out of the if statement, but then again, the if statements are all result of the browserify transformation, not from my original coding. Seems to me that Browserify wouldn't create a code that it doesn't support?

Comment: Browserify doesn't know if the module is meant only for server-side. So are trying to use knex on client?

Comment: I just check and the code is part of knex. So you are trying to use server-side code on client. **IT WON'T WORK.**