# esbuild + knex: Cannot find module '../../dialects/mysql/index.js'

Tags: typescript, knex.js, esbuild

I'm currently trying to migrate some code from javascript to typescript. This code uses the [knex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex) package. I am able to build and run it using `tsc`, but i would like to use `esbuild` instead (for faster build).

I build with:

```sh
npx esbuild index.ts --bundle --platform=node --sourcemap=external --outfile=dist/index.js
```

But when i try to run the compiled code, i get:

```
Cannot find module '../../dialects/mysql/index.js'
```

I have no idea what is this `dialect` directory, and couldn't find any documentatio about it. I took a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323425/mysql-dialect-cannot-be-fount-in-knex-browserified), but couldn't really understand the code in it, and the error seemed to be more about `browserified`.

Here is the code I used to reproduce the error:

```js
import Knex from 'knex';

const knex = Knex({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    port: 3306,
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'database',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
  },
});

const fetchData = async () => {
  const data = await knex('table')
    .select()
    .first();
  return data;
};

(async () => {
  const results = await fetchData();
  console.log(results);
})();
```

Interesting thing is that by using only the `mysql` package without `knex` worked great with both `tsc` and `esbuild`.

For some reason only the build from `esbuild` fails. I first thought i missed a package, and i installed [@types/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) and [@types/mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mysql) but it didn't solved my problem.

If it helps, i use the following `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem I've had as well and I came across a related thread on the [esbuild GitHub](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/473).

You'll just need to update your knex initialisation to the following:

```
import Knex from 'knex';
import KnexMysql from 'knex/lib/dialects/mysql';

const knex = Knex({
  client: KnexMysql,
  ...
});
```